# Google Home and FHEM?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, home-automation, ifttt, google-smart-home

I don't really like having to use IFTTT etc to control my smarthome. Everything is connected using fhem, and I don't want to change anything at that. But the Google Home / Google Assistant can't really control fhem. Only using IFTTT, external control over fhem etc. I just want the Google Assistant to control fhem over my wifi, not over Googles servers.

Is there any way to control it locally?
Huebridge, wemore etc all don't work...

**x** Is it maybe better to use Googles Speech API or so? Is it also as good as the Google Assistant at recognizing me?

**x** or can I use the Assistant SDK on my RPi to add commands that will be synced to the Google Home (Mini)? So that these commands go over the GASDK and can be given to fhem?

**x** or can that be done with Api.ai? It's complicated and what I know like Alexa's silly skills. Every time you have to confirm that you want to speak to the action (see examples from Google Developer site).

**o** or is there really only a chance with IFTTT? I don't have a security system or so that can be controlled with fhem, so it's not that bad when somebody "hacks" my fhem by knowing the address and commands.

Thanks for your answers,

Fabian

(wrong site again? thought the only one that fits is Stack Overflow)

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague and confusing. Are you trying to program something to work with an IoT device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Option with FHEM is IFTTT.

Best Option is to change to Home Assistant. It has native Google Home compatibility and works great. It has a better Ui than FHEM (imo), it has Auto-Detect etc.
If you want to use Google Assistant or Alexa with your DIY smart home, take a look at it. [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io)

Answer (score 2):

@Prisoner's answer is correct, that the behavior you want is infeasible. I'm unsure the extent of IFTTT's capabilities, so I don't think any local control is possible.

You could connect your Raspberry Pi to the Internet and run a [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) script on it which will receive requests from the Google Assistant and be able to route it to the devices on your network.

That would just need to be an Internet-facing Raspberry Pi and some simple logic to handle the JSON payloads. You would not need to use the Google Assistant SDK.

If you did use the SDK, you could not "sync" commands over to your Google Home Mini.

API.AI/Dialogflow would not be the right way to create Smart Home actions. Using the documentation above for Smart Home will give you the preferred way.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the smart home script idea

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to control it locally with Google Home and the Google Assistant - you can't. The Google Assistant relies on cloud controls to do most of its actions. Since most IoT has a cloud-based solution, this is a reasonable assumption to make.

Answer (score 0):

IFTTT would be indeed a possible option here. To make it secure, you'd need to develop some sort of API on your FHEM server (using both HTTPS and Key authentication or alike). I could imagine appending a query parameter to your query string in IFTTT containing a secure token, like `https://myendpoint.net/smarthomeapi/device/xyz?apikey=abcXYZ`

However, one of the main problem of IFTTT is that it only supports the limited command set you supply.

I've started to use [gBridge.io](https://about.gbridge.io), as an alternative for that solution, a while ago. It integrates into FHEM using MQTT servers. It integrates natively into Google's smart home api, so devices are actually shown in the Google Home app dashboard